# Eclipse cannot find java file generated via jsp on the work folder

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jsp, tomcat

I am currently programming using Eclipse 3.4.1 and using the Apache 5.5 as backend server. I am also using the com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.2.1 plugin for tomcat.

I was just wondering, when I encounter an error and prints the stack trace for the exception. I always would see the line code where the error occured on the java work file generated from JSP file. However, when I try to click on the link, it saids source not found for "org.apache.jsp.WResultReportList_jsp".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.WResultReportList_jsp._jspService(WResultReportList_jsp.java:381)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
```

I was wondering how I could configure eclipse to be able to find that work file and open the specific line of code where the error occurred?

Is it even possible to point the error to the location of the actual JSP file? Or is it just able to find the error line number for the java generated work file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> Link source...

Linked folder location: `C:\tomcat 7.0\work\Catalina\localhost\application_name`

Press "Finish".

Comment: remember to delete folder contents (or make an ant builder that does it) before build! and to refresh project before click on stacktrace line in console :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html) there is an Apache options to control whether the generated Java code is retained (the runtime needs only the class files). So you first should check whether the **keepgenerated** option is set to true (the documentation states that if it's not specified then the default is true).

After that a quick search for .java files should help you find them.

Comment: Hi djna, thanks. The Java source file are retained. I actually do this manually so i go to the work folder, open the generated java source file in the work folder. open the java file and search the line number manually. Maybe there must be another settings like a search path where i will need to add the work folder. So far, i could not find that settings in Eclipse though.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the java file generated by jsp
simply write this code in jsp file and run your application and follow the path 
which will display after successfully run

```
<%=getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class")%>
```

I found this usefull. 
Hope this will work.